# Combine two lists in Ansible when one list could be empty

Tags: list, ansible

actually I've a problem by compining two lists in Ansible to one new in case of one list could be empty or not.

EDIT:

One list is defined in defaults

```
standardvolumes: '/usr/share/zoneinfo:/usr/share/zoneinfo:ro'
```

and the other list could be defined in group_vars.yml for the hostgroup.

```
volumes:
    - '/usr/data:/data'
    - '/usr/data2:/data2'
    - '/usr/data3:/data3'
```

At the task I comine the lists:

```
  - name: Combine volume lists
    set_fact:
      volumestostart: '{{ standardvolumes|default([]) + volumes|default([]) }}'
```

In play I get this error:

```
TASK [do-docker-deployment : Combine volume lists] *****************************
fatal: [shs_de_postd_server1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ standardvolumes|default([]) + volumes|default([]) }}): coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found"}
```

So I've tried to redefine my defaults list:

```
standardvolumes: 
  - '/usr/share/zoneinfo:/usr/share/zoneinfo:ro'
```

But then I get a docker format error:

```
failed: [shs_de_postd_server1] (item={u'key': u'qit', u'value': {u'cgrouptype': u'blech', u'nexususer': u'cbs-qit-user', u'notstartable': u'no', u'nexuspassword': u'48vhw63u', u'nexusport': u'8191', u'nexuspath': u'ftg/postd-server', u'graylogip': u'tcp://10.20.30.40:12201'}}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": {"key": "qit", "value": {"cgrouptype": "blech", "graylogip": "tcp://10.20.30.40:12201", "nexuspassword": "48vhw63u", "nexuspath": "ftg/postd-server", "nexusport": "8191", "nexususer": "cbs-qit-user", "notstartable": "no"}}, "msg": "Found invalid volumes mode: ro']"}
```

The lists are docker volumes for a container which I will start with my role.

Anybody good ideas?

Thanks and regards,
David

Comment: See [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It would have been sufficient to ask: "How to concatenate two lists that might be undefined?" `list_A: "{{ list_A + list_B }}"`

Comment: That doesn't work when one list or both are undefined.

Comment: @gurbelunder The question could have been as short as that and was perfectly explaining the problem you are trying to solve: concatenate two lists that might be undefined.

Comment: For what it's worth: `standardvolumes` defined in defaults is not a list but a string in your above example.

Comment: I also tried it as list but then I get unclear docker errors. As you can see above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```yaml
  volumes: "{{ volumes|default([]) + standardvolumes|default([]) }}"
```

---

For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        list_A: "{{ list_A|default([]) + list_B|default([]) }}"
    - debug:
        var: list_A
```

give

```yaml
  list_A: []
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks good. Of course, just set the default no "nothing". But now I get another error, that my volume has the wrong format?

Comment: ``` ansible error
(item={u'key': u'qit', u'value': {u'cgrouptype': u'blech', u'nexususer': u'cbs-qit-user', u'notstartable': u'no', u'nexuspassword': u'48vhw63u', u'nexusport': u'8191', u'nexuspath': u'ftg/postd-server', u'graylogip': u'tcp://10.20.30.40:12201'}}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": {"key": "qit", "value": {"cgrouptype": "blech", "graylogip": "tcp://10.20.30.40:12201", "nexuspassword": "48vhw63u", "nexuspath": "ftg/postd-server", "nexusport": "8191", "nexususer": "cbs-qit-user", "notstartable": "no"}}, "msg": "Found invalid volumes mode: ro']"}
```

Comment: OK; I've found the format problem. But now this:

{"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ standardvolumes|default([]) + volumes|default([]) }}): coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found"}